# How to get full tweets in response from Twitter REST api

Tags: javascript, api, twitter

I have seen some questions but they did not seem to solve my issue, so hopefully i can provide enough information for this to be tackled. I am making a request thats looks like so. This is using the [Twit npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit)

```
 T.get('search/tweets', { q: '#love', count: 100, lang: 'en' }, 
       function (err, data, response) { console.log(data) };
```

This works fine and will return the request tweets, but many of so look like the following, in the text section of the response for each.

```
'random tweet about search criteria and lots of info blah lol etc...'
```

Is there a way I can retrieve the full text rather than what I am recieveing whislt interacting with the API using this method. More information can be added if needed about the whole response but trying to avoid as it is real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, hope resolve your issue

```
T.get('search/tweets', { q: '#love', count: 100, lang: 'en', tweet_mode:'extended'}, 
       function (err, data, response) { console.log(data) };
```

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else with similar problem this will return full_text for each, unless its a retweet, then handle appropriately.